# Laziness is a problem with many students

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, prepositional-phrases

I don't think the following sentence is grammatically correct:

> Laziness is a problem **with** many students.

Wouldn't it better to say:

> Laziness is a problem **for** many students.

or perhaps,

> Laziness is a problem among students.

It just sounds 'off' to use 'with' for me.

Comment: "Laziness is a problem with many students" could also suggest that the problem of laziness only exists when there are a lot of students, which is probably not what is meant

Answer (score 1):

A problem **with** would suggest that the subject is the source of the problem.

A problem **for** means that the subject has to deal with the problem.

So in case of laziness, it is a problem that students have to overcome, so it is a problem **for** them.

> Laziness is a problem for many students.
>
> Many students have problems with laziness.

General rule:

What is a problem **for** who?

Who has a problem **with** what?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; could you illustrate one example for the 'with' case? I couldn't really tell.

Comment: I have a problem **with** drugs. 
Drugs are a problem **for** me.